4060 TI (16gb) and 3060 (12gb) on the same pc with 750W psu, is that asking for trouble?
i currently have and 3060 on my pc, and i considering buy an 4060ti (16gb) for an upgrade, i know it's better save up more to get at least 4070 but there's a reason for me choose this set up
i want to migrate to linux but too bad my work are mostly on creative industry that heavily rely on windows, that when i remember, i can just fire up a vm with the right set up and do some gpu passthrough i can solely use that vm just for my work and linux as daily driver
and again gpu passthrough not gonna be optimal if i use 1 gpu,
also i'm trying to frugal here so i think if i gonna choose 4070 above i also need to upgrade the psu (and i try to avoid that).
and seeing how 4060 are basically just 3060 with extra step, i think if i use 4060 to linux and passthrough the 3060 to vm, my 750w psu should be able to hold it, is that a fools errand?
and after trying to see are there any thread with my specific need, there's none, that's i why post here,
my current spec are:

intel i9 10900kf

RTX 3060 (12gb)

128gb ram (2666 mhz) (-_-)

seasonic gx-750 psu



There are many PC power calculators on the internet, have you tried any of them? https://seasonic.com/wattage-calculator/

never heard of it, please excuse my noobness, thanks i'm gonna try it

Add your components to a new build configuration in pcpartpicker.com, and it'll give you an estimated wattage in the top-right corner. I started you off https://uk.pcpartpicker.com/list/dMwmXk

wow, i got estimated 525watt, which is nice, i still have 200watt left as offset to balance my workload, thanks man , i gotta use that more often to estimate other build as well

Another factor to keep in mind is that an "oversized" PSU will, to a certain limit, run more efficiently than one only sized just enough. In other words, when the components of a PSU are not being strained or run close to their limits by the system load, they will perform better and last longer and, generally (and to a limit) use less energy for their own needs.

From the specs for the NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060:
NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 12 GB draws... 170 W maximum. 

From the specs for the NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4060:
TDP [Thermal Design Power] 115 W

Suggested PSU 300 W

From the specs for Intel® Core™ i9-10900KF Processor:
TDP 125 W

Adding just those three TDP requirements: 115 W + 300 W + 125 W = 540 W, which is the maximum thermal (steady-state) dissipation. This does not take into account that for short periods, these devices may greatly exceed their TDP, nor does it take into account the other devices on the PCB, such as drive, RAM, NIC and fans.
From those numbers, it would seem a 750 W supply should work, until the PC is under heavy load.
Your experience may vary.

thank goodness for this info, many thanks, good thing my cpu and gpu was never been overclocked or needed to, so i'm glad my rig still have sufficient power then, i thought being 4 years running my pc has already slide to mid/bellow range spec for installing 40 series, especially the 30 also needed to still intact, glad to hear my plan sound possible

@DikikSahertian, Read more carefully: until the PC is under heavy load..

nahh, it will  be fine :)

you've been warned
